# why would an express route be overwritten by react router on aws but not localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, reactjs

I'm trying to create an api route to save lead data from my state in a react app. From my localhost, get and post work fine and when I go to the url, I get the a json, just as I wanted. However, when I sync these files to my amazon linux server, it uses the * route in my router instead of going to the correct url path.

here is what I have in server.js

```
app.use('/api/leads', leadRoute );

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'static/index.html')
});

app.get('/static/bundle.js', (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/bundle.js');
});

app.use('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/index.html')
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your code changes are in the container? If you modify something like the return, does it update?  You might want to note you're running in a container that I randomly know.

Comment: Yea, any other changes I've been making have shown up when I resync, and I've made some pretty significant ones as I had to be able to post to a CRM lead list. This for some reason, seems to be the only change that's not  sticking

Comment: I just tried to add a new route to just do res.send('hi'), and I get the same issue where locally it routes correctly, but on aws, react router overrides it

Comment: Try removing star route and see if others work on AWS. You can make certain changes that work without a server restart. Maybe you are having that issue where it is working from initial upload.

Comment: I mean node server restart btw

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't eliminate the not found aspect. I probably do need to restart the server then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that you are updating server-side code, and not restarting the server after the change.